# WARNING: Failed to load DLL from static location [ exception shown in jenkins agent command prompt ]

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

Hello I run jenkins agent like following, after running any job on this agent it showing error warning which is shown by bold text.

C:\apps\Jenkins_service>java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://localhostL8080/computer/vmamar01/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 850bab2a8bd0486e7db9365bd08d1801abc4ebbef9a449aa396fab682f53940e -noCertificateCheck
[
I skipped text here to print
......
]
INFO: Handshaking
....
....
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: iltlvvmsimjen.net.plm.eds.com
  Agent port:    54231
  Identity:      58:27:40:45:56:11:1d:1d:48:91:62:78:e4:5e:16:ab
.....
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 58:27:40:45:56:11:1d:1d:48:91:62:78:e4:5e:16:ab
Oct 09, 2023 4:04:40 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Oct 10, 2023 1:59:30 AM org.jvnet.winp.Native loadByUrl

****WARNING: Failed to load DLL from static location**
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Users\amar.jenkins\cache\jars\ED\winp.x64.BFFE30B3B50581290B1866EF8D48C609.dll already loaded in another classloader
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2700)
..............
..............**

checking dll and environment

Comment: Hi Anyone can try to resolve this.